# Python: get user from apache authnz_ldap

Tags: python, apache, ldap

I'm authenticating ldap users through Apache2's authnz_ldap module successfully. It is not clear to me how to fetch their username once they have logged in so that I can interact with them through any following forms/webpages. I've tried the typical ways (os.getenv os.environ getpass etc.) but they either just give me www-data or None result.

I suspect what I need is available in either an apache/ldap module, but I could use some help to search down the correct path. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How are you executing the Python code?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#exposed

Although the environment key was not documented, i threw in a few likely suspects and found that `os.getenv('AUTHENTICATE_UID')` was the winner.

I hope this saves someone some time.